# Entity framework - to use to not in this scenario

Tags: asp.net, .net, entity-framework, entity

Here is my problem:

I have 10 database (D1, D2, ....D10 ) with same schema but data is different in the tables. I do not have any control over these database as these belong to different companies.

Now I have to develop a website which will run on any of these database.
example I can run www.site.com/D1 or www.site.com/d2....like this..and the page will bring data from the respective database and render on page.

Can I use entity framework in this case? Is EF would be recommended here or normal stored procedure based approach will be fine? Can I reset the entity framework connection string pragmatically and load the information from respective database dynamically, will it have performance issues...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah you can do this with EF if you want. There is really only going to be one main difference that you encounter. **Which db to use?**

When you have a mechanism for determining which database will be accessed then 90% of your problem will be solved. The other 10% is simply using that mechanism to point to a `DbContext` which will be using that company's connection string.

So basically, in your web.config, you are going to have 10 unique connection strings defined with each name matched to the company. Then, using your determining mechanism, you will instantiate the matching DbContext and use that for your querying.

web.config

```
 <configuration>
  ...
  <connectionStrings>
   <add name="PepsiDbContext" connectionString="conn string here" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
   <add name="ColaDbContext" connectionString="conn string here" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
 </configuration>
```

DAL.cs

```
public class EntityStructure : DbContext
{
  public DbSet<Table1> TableName1s { get; set; }
  public DbSet<Table2> TableName2s { get; set; }
}

public class PepsiDbContext : EntityStructure {}
public class ColaDbContext : EntityStructure {}
```

querying

```
if( company.Name == "Pepsi" )
{
 using( var db = new PepsiDbContext() )
 {
  //query
 }
}else
{
 using( var db = new ColaDbContext() )
 {
  //query
 }
}
```

The querying part here is *over simplified* on purpose. It is where 90% of your implementation is going to take place. Actually instantiating the different database contexts is what this demo shows, and it should be rather trivial.